# Has anyone ever read the Java Language Specification(JLS)?

Tags: java

I recently had a question about String and String interning - pretty simple question which I got a quick answer to. But lo and behold I got a detailed answer to that same question on pg. 29 of the JLS 3<sup>rd</sup> Edition. It's really interesting that a lot of the questions we asked are answered in the JLS but its such a boring 600 page read (the 4<sup>th</sup> Edition is even bigger). How bout you guys how many of you have picked up the JLS lately for a leisurely read?

Comment: 4th Edition? Actually the first edition was quite big (but it did include some of the "core" APIs).

Comment: The specification needs to be accurate, so all yes/no
 questions can be answered definitively.  Thise who wrote
and maintained java compilers /must/ have read it
to be able to know how to implement Them.

Comment: I'm tempted to reopen this, so we can enjoy page after page of people saying "Yes, I've read it recently", or "No, I haven't read it for a while", or "I keep a copy in the bathroom".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've referenced it a couple of times, but for light reading I enjoy the [VM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I have read all three editions, but not recently. Some of it is really dull (Chapter 16 on Definite Assignment, for example). But I rarely find I need to look something up, and I'm not about to for a question on this site. Really a lot of questions should simply be answered with a reference to docs or a bugs database.

Comment: How long did it take you to read all three editions?

Answer (score 0):

I read a good chunk of it five or six years back for a compilers class.  We were tasked with implementing random bits of the Java compiler and my intention was to go way past what the assignments actually entailed.  It was one of the most fun and interesting projects I ever did, especially seeing it work.  I never did complete it, though - didn't even really get as far as generating bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes read things from here and there, when there is something specific that I need to find out (for example details of how [Java's memory model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4) is defined). I have never read the full JLS. I suppose that only language implementors will need to read it all.